# What does 'asymptotic' refer to in the derivation of the heat equation?

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics

In my Fourier analysis class we spent some time deriving the heat equation. The basic set up was that we have an infinitesimal square of length $h$ centred at a point $x_0,y_0$.

We derive the equation in 'two' steps essentially (we have already established the function for total heat on the square, $H(t) = \sigma \int_S u(x,y,t) dxdy$).

Step 1 is to just note by the Leibniz integral rule that $$H'(t) = \frac{dH}{dt} = \sigma \int_S \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} (x,y,t)dxdy$$ Then we said that as $h$ tends to $0$, we have that this value is asymptotically $H'(t) \approx \sigma h^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x_0,y_0,t)$ for the point we are interested in.

Step 2 is via Newton's law of cooling, and we establish that:

$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial t} \propto k \bigg[\color{blue}{h \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0 + \frac{h}{2}, y_0, t) - h \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0 - \frac{h}{2}, y_0, t)} + \color{red} {h \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0  + \frac{h}{2}, t) - h \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0  - \frac{h}{2}, t)}\bigg]$$

Here we again say that the $\color{blue}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}$ and $\color{red}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}}$ terms in the previous equation are 'asymptotic' to $h^2 \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x_0,y_0,t)$ and $h^2 \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2}(x_0,y_0,t)$ respectively.

I don't understand the asymptotic relationships in both steps. In the lecture, this was said without much explanation and I think it's meant to be obvious/common. Unfortunately I am not sure what it means.

We previously covered big O notation, and I've seen some answers on the site where asymptotic behaviour essentially refers to big O notation. But I don't see how this interpretation is used in this particular derivation. Specifically, in the second step for example, I have no idea why $\color{blue}{h \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0 + \frac{h}{2}, y_0, t) - h \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0 - \frac{h}{2}, y_0, t)}$ should be bounded by $h^2 \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x_0,y_0,t)$. (which is exactly the definition of big O notation we were taught)

Can anyone give any insight into what asymptotic means in this context, or if it is the same as big O notation, any insight into why I should expect the relevant functions to be bounded?

Comment: "X is asymptotic to Y" usually means "X approaches Y in the limit understood in the context", which here is $h \to 0$. (Sometimes it has a somewhat more subtle meaning; if you're interested, look up the term "asymptotic expansion". But this is not relevant here.) The situation here should really be pretty intuitive: you just need to expand $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$.

Comment: @Ian Ah thank you... I think I see why it's meant to be obvious now. Am I right that we just factor out the $h$, and then multiply and divide by $h$ to apply the definition of the derivative?

Comment: Pretty much. Then you have a factor of $h^2$ floating on the outside. Do you see what that's for (physically)?

Comment: @Ian Oh that's a good question... I didn't really think about it because we immediately cancelled that term away! But from the way we set up the derivation, I would think it is the physical term representing the contribution from the size of the perimeter? (But then that doesn't really fit with it being a square rather than $4h$)

Comment: The extra $h^2$ is the area of the region you integrated over. If you divide by $h^2$ to get the heat *density* at the point, then you can send $h \to 0$ and get a nonzero limit.